# duplicate the mesh in edit mode and flip normals using python script

Tags: python, normals, command-line

I want to make my two sided (input model is collada). so, for that i want to duplicate all the faces in edit mode and then flip normals, and then export the model as fbx. i want to do this using python script.

my command to run the python script is

```
blender --background --python MeshDuplicate.py
```

Below is the .py file i am calling:

```
import bpy
import sys

object = bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath="H:\\models\\armour.dae")
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
dup_object = bpy.data.objects.get("object")
object_d = dup_object.copy()
object_d.data = object.data.copy()
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(dup_object)
scene.update()  
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="H:\\models\\armour.fbx", axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

i am getting this error.

Read new prefs: C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\config\userpref.blend
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 96000hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\python
Writing node id='node', name='node'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\MeshDuplicate_Flip.py", line 11, in 
    object_d = dup_object.copy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

Answer (score 2):

**Operators return a set**

Operators return a status in a set. If the operator has worked it returns `{'FINISHED'}` and if cancelled `{'CANCELLED'}`

Hence in this line

```
object = bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath="H:\\models\\armour.dae")
```

if the import succeeded the return value is `{'FINISHED'}`  *Note `object` is a python built in, the basic python object type, and is best not used as a variable*

As answered by @Crantisz the error occurs because your  `dup_obj is None` *Unless there is an object in the blend named "object"... ..unlikely??*

```
dup_object = bpy.data.objects.get("object")
```

*Note: there is no correlation between having a variable named "object" and there being a blender object named "object".*

**Alternative method**

After an import operator has run succesfully, most importers set the newly imported objects as selected and one as active. *Test this by checking in UI for different importers, This is recommended default behaviour.*

After a successful import the active object is

```
# straight after import operator
#active_newly_imported object_

ob = context.object
# list of all newly imported objects
imported_obs = context.selected_objects
```

Using bmesh to flip normals removes the need for edit mode toggling required to use the mesh operator.

Test script (untested). After import, Read each newly imported mesh object into a bmesh, flip the normals, write back to mesh... rinse repeat.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context 
bm = bmesh.new()
bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath="H:\\models\\armour.dae")
meshobjs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type=='MESH']
for ob in meshobjs:
    me = ob.data
    bm.from_mesh(me) # load bmesh
    for f in bm.faces:
        f.normal_flip()
    bm.normal_update() # not sure if req'd
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()
    bm.clear() #.. clear before load next
    
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
        filepath="H:\\models\\armour.fbx", 
        axis_forward='-Z', 
        axis_up='Y')
```

Finally there could be a chance your axis transformation inverts scale which can also produce flipped normals.

Comment: is there any way to also flip custom normals using bmesh or any other technique? Since a few Blender versions there is `bpy.context.object.data.flip_normals()`, which produces the same result as your script above, but both approaches don't flip custom normals correctly. Only `bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals()` gives the result I'd want.

Answer (score 1):

Then you get this error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

This means, that you try to get attribute from object 'NoneType'. NoneType is nothing.  So you want to get something from none. Why `dup_object` is None? You will get 'NoneType' when try to get object, that doesn't exists. I guess there is no object with name `""object""`. Why name is "object"? - check this.